# Is there a way to pass a Class variable to Espresso ActivityTestRule?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-espresso

I am writing tests for Activities using Espresso. For each activity, the test looks something like this

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TestSomeActivity {
    @get:Rule
    var activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(SomeActivity::class.java, true, false)
    @Test
    fun testNullIntent() {
        val intent = Intent()
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

What this does is whenever an Intent inside that Activity calls `intent.getExtra`, `null` is returned.

The problem is, if we are to check this for every activity the same code has to be written except for this line-

```
@get:Rule
var activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(SomeActivity::class.java, true, false)
```

To solve this problem, I got the name of all the activities using `PackageManager` and converted them to `Class`. Then I tried passing this class to my `activityTestRule`.

```
val intent = Intent()
val activityInfoList = getAllActivities()
for(activityInfo in activityInfoList!!) {
    val className = activityInfo.applicationInfo.className
    val activityClass = Class.forName(className)
    val activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(activityClass.javaClass, true, false)
    activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent)
}
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in compile time error-

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
<init>(SingleActivityFactory<T!>!, Boolean, Boolean)   where T cannot be inferred for    constructor ActivityTestRule<T : Activity!>(activityFactory: SingleActivityFactory<T!>!, initialTouchMode: Boolean, launchActivity: Boolean) defined in androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
<init>(Class<T!>!, Boolean, Boolean)   where T cannot be inferred for    constructor ActivityTestRule<T : Activity!>(activityClass: Class<T!>!, initialTouchMode: Boolean, launchActivity: Boolean) defined in androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
```

To solve this we tried to convert activityClass to Activity using

```
val activityClass = Class.forName(className) as Activity
val activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(activityUnderTest.javaClass, true, false)
```

which eliminated the compile time error but introduced `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`.

Is there a way to run the same Espresso script for all the activities in a class or pass a `Class` to ActivityTestRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this piece of code

```
val activityClass = Class.forName(className) as Activity
```

You can use the following

```
val activityClass = Class.forName(className) as Class<Activity>
```

This would ensure that you won't get the compile-time error, and the type-cast exception won't happen after you run your code.